# After fresh installation, Jupyter notebook is asking for password

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

1. Ran the jupyter notebook using jupyter notebook in cmd
2. Ran it using anaconda prompt
3. Ran it normally with jupyter notebook launcher.

In all the above scenarios, the notebook asks for a password, the password was never set up, tried it with PC password, but still any success.

Changed the browser from firefox to chrome. But no success.

Comment: I encounter the same problem but not with fresh installation but after jupyter is upgraded automatically while installing vpython.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it,

disabling jupyter Notebook Password

First open Anaconda Prompt

Enter the following command
`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

From jupyter directory ,edit the jupyter_notebook_config.py using notepad
make changes into the jupyter_notebook_config.py using notepad.

`c.NotebookApp.token = ''`

`c.NotebookApp.password = ''`

`c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True`

`c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'`

There should be a config JSON file, edit that file, In the password key, make its value an empty string.

Now launch the jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator or from cmd.

Comment: May I know since when it happens? I install VPython, which eventually upgrade jupyter-kernel and other packages. Since then Jupyter Notebook requies password, even to access folders and files.

Answer (score 2):

**You can just use the following command when opening the Jupiter notebook.**

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
```